# How to compare multiple extension-less files in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm new to bash shell scripting.
How can I compare 8 outputs of extension-less files (with only binary values) - same length of values, 0 or 1.
To clarify things, this is what I've done so far.

```
for d in */; do
find . -name base -execdir sh -c 'cat {} >> out' \;
done
```

> I've Found all the files that are located in sub-folders, read & concatenated all the binary files into out file.

Now I have 8 out files (8 parent folders) that I need to compare with.

I've tried both **"diff"** and **"cmp"** - but they both work only with 2 files.

At the end, I need to check and verify if there is a difference between this 8 binary files and eventually to export the results and represent them in HEX format - example: if 2 of the out files are all '1' = F , and if all '0'  = 0 . hence, the final results should be for example : **FFFF 0000** (4 first files are all '1' , 4 last files are all '0').

What is the best option to do so? - Hope that I've managed to clarify my case.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: What are binary txt files? Either you have txt=text files (which are not considered binary) or you have binary files (which are not considered text). That your files have the extension `.txt` is not important; file extensions are just a convention for naming files. Of course a "wrong" file extension could lead to confusion.

Comment: Hi @Socowi , My binary files are shown without an extension, it's simply a file that contains 0 or 1 in its value when I open it. - Hope that helped

Comment: I'm confused. You claimed that your files where shown without extensions although you clearly wrote *"I have 8 **out.txt** that I need to compare"*. Are there other files involved? I think it would be best if you could give us a minimal command generating your eight example files (for instance `printf '\x01' > file1` ... `printf '\x00' > file8`) and a minimal command showing the expected output (for instance `cat file` printing `FFFF0000`). After that you should clarify what could differ from the example input. For instance, are your input files always exactly one byte long, etc.? What if not?

Comment: I have this 8 **out.txt** files out of concatenation ("cat") of **16** binary files in each sub-directory respectively, as you can see in the code that I've published.
So this 8 out.txt values are always 16bits (or 2 bytes) long because of the merge.
So I don't need to generate input files, because I already got them in the sub-directories. regarding the expected final HEX output, I'm still struggling to compare between the 8 outputs of each directory.
My inputs that are located in the sub-directories, they are always 1 bit long - value **0** or **1**. - Hope that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume:

- We have 8 (presumably binary) files, say: `dir1/out.txt`, `dir2/out.txt`, ..
  `dir8/out.txt`.
- We want to compare among these files and identify which files are identical
  and which are not.

Then how about the steps:

1. To generate hash values of the files with e.g. `sha256sum`.
2. To compare the hash values and divide into groups based on the hash values.

I have created 8 test files, of those dir1/out.txt, dir2/out.txt and dir4/out.txt
  are indentical, dir3/out.txt and dir7/out.txt are identical, and others
  differ.

Then the hash values will look like:

```
sha256sum dir*/out.txt

298497ad818c3d927498537ed5ab4f9ae663747b6d00ec9a5d0bd9e30a6b714b  dir1/out.txt
298497ad818c3d927498537ed5ab4f9ae663747b6d00ec9a5d0bd9e30a6b714b  dir2/out.txt  
e962879ef251f2117460cf0d5ce714e36a9ab79f2548c48e2121b4e573cf179b  dir3/out.txt  
298497ad818c3d927498537ed5ab4f9ae663747b6d00ec9a5d0bd9e30a6b714b  dir4/out.txt
f45151f5253c62de69c95935f083b5649876fdb661412d4f32065a7b018bf68b  dir5/out.txt  
bdc26931acfb734b142a8d675f205becf27560dc461f501822de13274fe6fc8a  dir6/out.txt  
e962879ef251f2117460cf0d5ce714e36a9ab79f2548c48e2121b4e573cf179b  dir7/out.txt  
11a77c3d96c06974b53d7f40a577e6813739eb5c811b2a86f59038ea90add772  dir8/out.txt
```

To summarize the result, let me replace the hash values with *group id*, having
the same number for the same files in occurance order.

Here's the script:

```
sha256sum dir*/out.txt | awk '{if (!gid[$1]) gid[$1] = ++n; print $2 " " gid[$1]}'
```

The output:

```
dir1/out.txt 1
dir2/out.txt 1
dir3/out.txt 2
dir4/out.txt 1
dir5/out.txt 3
dir6/out.txt 4
dir7/out.txt 2
dir8/out.txt 5
```

where the second field shows the *group id* to indicate which files are identical.

Note that the *group id* does not represent the content of each file as:
`if 2 of the out.txt files are all '1' = F , and if all '0' = 0`,
because I have no idea how the files look like. If OP can provide the
example files, I could be more help.
BTW I'm still in doubt if the files *are* binary in ordinary sense because
OP is mentioning that "it's simply a file that contains 0 or 1 in its
value when I open it". It sounds to me the files are composed of
ascii "0"s and "1"s. My script above should work for both binary files
and text files anyway.

**[Update]**

According to the OP's information, here's a solution for the specific case:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in dir*/out.txt; do
    if [[ $(uniq "$f" | wc -l) = 1 ]]; then
        echo -n "$(head -1 "$f" | tr 1 F)" 
    else
        echo -n "-" 
    fi
done
echo
```

It digests the contents of each file to either of: `0` for all 0's, `F` for all 1's or `-` for the mixture case (possible error).
For instance, if dir{1..4}/out.txt are all 0's, dir5/out.txt is a mixture, and dir{6..8}/out.txt are all 1's, then the output will look like:

```
0000-FFF
```

I hope it will meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, the comparison between the output files worked.
Yes, I suppose that my input files are basically represented as ASCII "0" or "1".
Regarding the HEX representation, SS example attached.
example for "0"s - http://tinypic.com/r/24yvi9h/9 , for "1"s - http://tinypic.com/r/rbfzao/9

Comment: Thanks for uploading the pictures. How many variations do the files have? All 0's or all 1's (just two variations)? Or do they include mixture of 0's and 1's (possibly randomly)?

Comment: Basically yes, only 2 variations - all 1's and all 0's. But I need also to validate if this is the actual case. So I think the divide to 3 groups will be sufficient. for example: group id 1: all 1, id 2: all 0, and group 3: if there is some kind of mixture by accident - it can be represented as individual false case or some kind of general error, because the system should work only with all 1's or all 0's. So the final HEX representation could be like: **0000FFFF** or **0F0FF0F0** etc.

Comment: Very clear. I've updated my answer according to the information. Would you please test it?

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it's working.
One last thing that I need a little bit help with is: how can I move the **out.txt** output file to its parent folder respectively.
During the `find . -name "" -execdir sh -c 'cat {} >> out.txt' \;` the file is created in each of the sub-folders, there is a way to move them or at least copy them to the parent folder. Because I don't realy need those files in each of the sub-folders, I need them only at the parent folders (8 parent folder, 1 out.txt file in each of them).

Comment: **Update:** When I've tried to add `find -name out -execdir mv -f {} .. \;` to the code, the final export of the file is **1 bit** long - 1 or 0 instead of **16bit**. And when I've tried to replace **mv** with **cp** it did work. There is an option to move the output file to the parent folder in a different way maybe?

Comment: First of all, the 8 files have the same name `out.txt` right? If so, the filenames will collide to each other if they are moved or copied back to the parent folder. You will need to rename them under certain rule. I would keep them in the subfolders because I don't feel the problem. Would you please illustrate the directory tree you are working with? BTW I'm afraid I cannot understand your saying "the file is 1 bit long". As you know the unit of the file length is byte, not bit. BR.

Comment: Yes, all of the 8 file have the same name "out.txt" , when I've tried **cp** the file overwrite itself and managed to keep the same value of the child - 16 0's \ 1's.
in **mv** the outcome was only 1 value long - 0 \ 1. I prefer to move the files or to delete the files in the child sub-folders because if I need to perform the test several times it will always merge them to the existing out.txt files that are located in the sub-folders. Regarding the directory tree structure it will be for example /sys/class/gpio/chip**/$$  | ** represent the 8 parent folders, $$ represent the 16 childs.

Comment: **Update:** My current challenge is to find a way how to concatenate the values of each sub-folders (child's) in the parent folders respectively. Because in the current state I get `out.txt` in each sub-folder and I can't just move or copy this file to the parent folder and overwrite it, because I need to check also for a scenario that one of the child's value isn't identical to the same 15 child in the group (parent folder). For example: In parent folder #1: 14 child's values  are 1's and 2 child's values are 0's. can I overcome this during the `find` and `cat` stages, If not so how then?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get your problem. Do you mention that when
you move a file with 16 0's or 1's, then the moved file turns out to
hold only one 0 or 1? It is beyond my understanding and I'm afraid
I can't help you out.

Comment: Yes, it happens only when I add this to the current code and only with `mv`.
during: `find . -name "" -execdir sh -c 'cat {} >> out' \;` I get `out` file in each sub-folder and I can't just move or copy this file to the parent folder and overwrite it.
I need to concatenate the values of each sub-folders (16 children) in their parent folders (8) respectively, so that in each parent folder there will be a output file that should contains 16 ASCII values of 0 or 1 (merge of the 16 children).
My questions is can I overcome this during the `find` and `cat` stage ? -Thanks

Comment: The move or copy code that I've used for testing is: `find -name out -execdir cp -t ../ {} +` or `find -name out -execdir mv -t ../ {} +`

Comment: BTW why you specify "" as a `-name` option?

Comment: Just for convenience sake, I'll edit this.
But what about my question?

Comment: Let me suggest not to abuse `find` especially when generating files unless
you are very clear what you are doing. Your usage of `find` may spread
the file `out` around, sometimes as an input, sometimes as an output.
Instead please try to say: `cd /sys/class/gpio; for d in chip*; do cat "$d"/*/* > "$d"/out; done`

Answer (score 0):

### If you are looking for records that are unique in your list of files

```
cat $path/$files|uniq -u>/tmp/output.txt
grep -f /tmp/output.txt $path/$files
```